# Filter the suggestion in Autocomplete

Tags: here-api

I'm using https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest and I would like to know how can you filter the response for just having category: administrative-region in the suggestions ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Currently filter by category is possible in Explore resource of places API not in Autocomplete API where you can specify the category Id to filter the result as below-

```
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=40.74917,-73.98529&cat=900-9200-0218&cs=pds&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy
```

> By setting the parameter **cat=900-9200-0218&cs=pds**

also **not** all the category can be applied in the filter as they are RESTRICTED.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/category-900-areas-buildings.html